# gruntjs: Rename Files + Folders as Task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

if have a few files:

```
_file1.css
_folder1
...>
    _file2.css
    _file4.css
    _folder3
         _file5.css
```

I want to **remove all the "_"** from all filenames an folder-names. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [grunt-copy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-copy) module and [grunt-clean](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-clean) module.  You can copy the directory structure and rename the files, then clean out the old ones (if needed).

Alternatively, there is the grunt-rename module.

The problem with both of these methods is that you may need many commands (potentially one per file / folder).  A quick google turned up a [custom grunt plugin](https://github.com/kashiif/grunt-file-regex-rename) that does regex based renaming, which may be the simplest way to do a batch rename in one command.